# How to get the text from an AttributedString initialized with markdown?

Tags: ios, swift

Using AttributeString that is inited with markdown:

`AttributedString(styledMarkdown: "# header")`

How can I get just only the text `header`?

This fails `XCTAssertEqual(attributedString, "header")` because attributedString is

```
header {
    NSPresentationIntent = [header 1 (id 1)]
}
```

Comment: `String(attributedString.characters)`?

Comment: @Larme that is the answer! Also, figured out you can do NSAttributedString(attributedString).string. If you want to post an answer below I'll select it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSAttributedString` (in `UIIKit`/`TextKit` has a `string` property.

You can go from `NSAttributedString` to `AttributedString` to do so:

```
let nsAttributedString = NSAttributedString(attributedString)
let stringWithoutTags = nsAttributedString.string
```

You can also use `characters` of `AttributedString`:

```
let stringWithoutTags = String(attributedString.characters)
```